# Error: function is not defined when calling a function returned by another function

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I am trying to write a function that returns another function. My goal is to write a function that takes an object and returns another function "search". When I call the search function with a key, I want to return the value of that key from the object given in the first function.

```
propertyOf = function(object) {
    return search = function (key) {
    for (key in object)
        if (key === object.property){
            return object[property]
        }
     }
  }
```

Say I have an object:

```
var me = {name: "Bob", age: 87}
```

If I call `propertyOf (me)` , I get [Function: search] as the result. When I call `search (age)` I get the error that search is not defined.  How do I call the 'inside' function with a key while still referencing which object I want to search?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/tubixusevi/1/edit?js,console — I can't reproduce the problem you describe. Try providing a real [mcve].

Comment: Aside: There's no point in `propertyOf` returning anything if you're going to ignore the return value and just use a global created by the function.

Comment: *"key = object.property"* should be **key == object.property**

Comment: search function is defined but it is that function what returns "undefined", since condition in if statement is never met and there's no other return for the case when element wasn't found

Comment: You will need to learn about local variables and how to declare them with  `var`.

Comment: @ derloopkat - thanks for catching that! I've changed it in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider trying this:

```
let bob = {
  name: 'Bob',
  age: 87
},
searchBob;

propertyOf = object => {
  return propName => {
    for (let key in object) {
  if(key === propName) return object[key]
    }
  }
}

searchBob = propertyOf(bob);

// Call it like this:

console.log(searchBob('age')); // 87
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do, thanks! Just to clarify the use of the => arrow: I want to write it in the traditional notation and I've replaced the first two lines of the function with: ' propertyOf = function (object) {
  return propName = function () { ' but I no longer get the correct output, it just says undefined. What am I doing wrong with my syntax? And why don't I have to put (key) as a parameter for the second function?

Comment: And what is the purpose of having 'searchBob' at the top above the function?

Comment: Sorry one more question as I'm working through this code - is 'propName' the name of a function? If so, what does it mean to evaluate whether (key === propName)? Especially confused because that is INSIDE the function so how can the code check if the function equals the key?